# How can I know what component failed?

Tags: talend

[image]

When using the **On SubJob Error** trigger, I would like to know what component failed inside the subjob. I have read that you can check the error message of each component and select the one that is not null. But I feel this practice is bad. Is there any variable that stores the identity of the component that failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I'm afraid there isn't. This is because globalVar elements are component-scoped (ie they are get/set by components themselves), not subjob-scoped (this would mean being set by Talend itself, or something). When the subjobError signal is triggered, you loose any component-based data coming from tFileInputDelimited. For this design reason, I don't think you will be able to solve your problem without iterating inside the globalMap searhcing for the error strings here and there.

Alternatively you can use tLogCatcher, which has a 'origin' column, to spot the offending component and eventually route to different recoverable subjobs depending on which component went to exception. This is not a design I trust too much, actually, because tLogCatcher is job-scoped, while OnSubjobError is directly linked to a specific subjob only. But It could work in simple cases

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example. You are right; The architecture is not trustworthy but it could work in simple cases